# Is there a way I can change the backup path for the notebook instance in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Is there a way I can change the backup path for the notebook instance in GCP?

I tried a couple of way, but I couldn't change it nor could find any materials with supporting information

I already created an instance a year ago. Need to change the properties. Any alternate suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Notebooks API Update metadata method [UpdateInstanceMetadataItems](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.instances/updateMetadataItems) or Compute API to change the following metadata attribute: `gcs-data-bucket`

Example:

`gcs-data-bucket=my-notebook-backup-bucket`

where `my-notebook-backup-bucket` is the GCS bucket.